# Adding only unique values into Realm

Tags: android, realm

Is there an elegant way to add a batch of new objects from JSON, taking into consideration that the new bunch might contain values that already in DB and that DB must contain only unique values?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not using the same id in the JSON object?, check that a unique id is being sent from the server and prepare a method that checks out for the id if it exists.

```
//Check if item exists already with id

public boolean checkIfExists(String id){

    RealmQuery<Data> query = realm.where(Data.class)
            .equalTo("id", id);

    return query.count() != 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I see the approach you suggested, but it isn't very convenient to me, because the app will read the bunch of json from file. 
I'm using `Realm.createAllFromJson(Class<E>, InputStream)` method which is very helpful in this situation. So it'd be nice if Realm engine itself takes responsibility of add unique values only into the storage.

Comment: Christian from Realm here. We have Primary keys in the pipeline, which should fix this this issue. However we have some blockers before it can be implemented fully. So for now the above answer is the only way. The pull request for Primary Key support can be found here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/565

Comment: the return statement can be simplified to

      return query.count() != 0;

Comment: true! also simplified further to return realm.where(Data.class)
            .equalTo("id", id).count() != 0;

Comment: The bunch of simplifiers :)